# Rake 'assets:precompile' failing on deploying to AWS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, ruby-on-rails-5

I tried to deploy my Rails app to AWS, using Capistrano.

After I ran `cap production deploy` I got a 'Rake Aborted' message with the following trace:

```
ExecJS::ProgramError: SyntaxError: Unexpected character '’' (line: 19420, col: 10, pos: 548371)

Error
    at new JS_Parse_Error (<eval>:3623:11948)
    at js_error (<eval>:3623:12167)
    at parse_error (<eval>:3623:14184)
    at Object.next_token [as input] (<eval>:3623:19902)
    at next (<eval>:3623:21852)
    at subscripts (<eval>:3624:1389)
    at expr_atom (<eval>:3623:31205)
    at maybe_unary (<eval>:3624:1752)
    at expr_ops (<eval>:3624:2523)
    at maybe_conditional (<eval>:3624:2615)
new JS_Parse_Error ((execjs):3623:11948)
js_error ((execjs):3623:12167)
parse_error ((execjs):3623:14184)
Object.next_token [as input] ((execjs):3623:19902)
next ((execjs):3623:21852)
subscripts ((execjs):3624:1389)
expr_atom ((execjs):3623:31205)
maybe_unary ((execjs):3624:1752)
expr_ops ((execjs):3624:2523)
maybe_conditional ((execjs):3624:2615)
/Users/apple/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/execjs-2.7.0/lib/execjs/ruby_racer_runtime.rb:47:in `rescue in block in call'
/Users/apple/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/execjs-2.7.0/lib/execjs/ruby_racer_runtime.rb:44:in `block in call'
/Users/apple/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/execjs-2.7.0/lib/execjs/ruby_racer_runtime.rb:75:in `block in lock'
/Users/apple/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/execjs-2.7.0/lib/execjs/ruby_racer_runtime.rb:73:in `Locker'
/Users/apple/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/execjs-2.7.0/lib/execjs/ruby_racer_runtime.rb:73:in `lock'
/Users/apple/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/execjs-2.7.0/lib/execjs/ruby_racer_runtime.rb:43:in `call'
/Users/apple/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/uglifier-3.0.4/lib/uglifier.rb:184:in `run_uglifyjs'
/Users/apple/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/uglifier-3.0.4/lib/uglifier.rb:146:in `compile'
```

This doesnt give me a particular location for the syntax error, how do I locate it?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5):

A more universal way to find the problem that use this code as bellow:

Run `rails console`

```
JS_PATH = "app/assets/javascripts/**/*.js"; 
Dir[JS_PATH].each do |file_name|
  puts "\n#{file_name}"
  puts Uglifier.compile(File.read(file_name))
end
```

It will show you the file and the line where the `Uglifier` is making the problem.

Comment: ¡What an awesome code!  Thank you... I could solve my problems in to work with my deploy @khanhpham